# loading an external properties file in udf

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

When writing a UDF let's say a EvalFunc, is it possible to pass a configuration file with

```
properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("conf/config.properties"));
```

when running in Hadoop Mode?

Best,
Will

Answer (score 4):

Here is `Simple Example to Read and Write files from Hadoop DFS` from http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopDfsReadWriteExample

maybe you can find some useful code in it to complete your job.

Following is my code, it successfully load a properties file in hadoop, I used the `Apache Commons Configuration` http://commons.apache.org/configuration/

```
public static void loadProperites(String path) throws ConfigurationException, IOException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    Path inFile = new Path(path);
    FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(inFile);

    PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
    config.load(in);

    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Apache Commons Configuration2 and vfs2:

```java
Parameters params = new Parameters();
FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration> builder =
                    new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                            .configure(params.fileBased().setFileSystem(new VFSFileSystem())
                                    .setLocationStrategy(new FileSystemLocationStrategy())
                                    .setEncoding("UTF-8").setFileName(propertyPath));
config = builder.getConfiguration();
```